# Ajax triggered PHP stored procedure throws 500 error reponse for large data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, stored-procedures, laravel-4

My site handles more than half million records. A PHP stored procedure call was triggered using an ajax call from the webpage. When too many data comes in the procedure takes too much time, which results in a request timeout. But the stored procedure is executed.

We increased the Apache timeout. But we can't depend on that for longer run. Since the procedure takes 2 or 3 mins to run now. I use Laravel 4.1 framework for the website. Is there an optimized way of resolving this issue?

Ajax Call

```
$.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + '/matchload',
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
        matchLoad();    
        console.log('success');

        },
    type: 'GET'
});
```

Comment: why don't you make a system call? command line php ..?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I am not aware of that can you explain please.

Comment: how do you trigger the procedure via ajax call?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I have a Laravel controller function that executes the stored procedure. A route named matchload is pointed to that function. the ajax call is updated in the question..

Comment: Whenever you see a 500 error, the first thing you should do is check the web server log.

Comment: @Devon we did and found the reason. We fixed it by increasing the timeout. But we are looking for an optimized way. Since the data will be keep on growing

Comment: @winnyboy5, sorry, I skimmed based on the title.  You probably need to change your php max_input_time and post_max_size.

Comment: @Devon gone through that. Still we are looking for a better way. since the data will grow in the coming days.

Comment: @winnyboy5, a better way for what exactly?  If it takes that long to import your data, you could split it up, or even compress it, but beyond that, if you have that much data to import, you have that much data to import.

Comment: Look into "chunking" in laravel, which allows you to send chunks of your data in each call.   That way you could avoid the timeout altogether.

Comment: @Devon stored procedure forces load on the database. so thinking on optimizing the stored procedure and Mysql settings for large datas.

Comment: Increasing timeouts is only a temporary solution and sending chunks won't help you in this case. You need to optimize the stored procedure that it's response does not take longer with more data or you need to implement a queue/pool pattern, where the AJAX call creates a new job, gets a URL to periodically check for the job status/response, a backend worker then crunches through the job and stores the result to a place, where the front end can pick it up. I can elaborate on that a bit more if you want.

Comment: @OndřejHlaváček Ya sure. Please elaborate...